# Evented, Threaded, and Go Routines, why not used more?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm, go

The Evented and Threaded models are quite popular and are usually discussed a lot.

The 'Threaded' approach, where every I/O operation can block, is simpler. It's easier to write and debug synchronous code, and the fact of the matter is that most ecosystems provide blocking I/O libraries, just use a thread pool, configure it properly and you're good to go.

But.. it doesn't scale.

And then there's the 'Evented' approach, where there is one thread (or one per cpu) that never blocks and performs only CPU instructions. When IO returns, it activates the appropriate computation, allowing better utilization of the CPU.

But.. it's harder to code, easier to create unreadable spaghetti code, there aren't enough libraries for async I/O etc... And non-blocking and blocking I/O don't mix well. It's very problematic to use in ecosystems that weren't designed from the ground up to be non-blocking. In NodeJS all I/O is non-blocking from the beginning (because javascript never had an I/O library to begin with). Good luck trying to implement the same in C++/Java. You can try your best, but it would take one synchronous call to kill your performance.

And then came Go. I started looking into Go recently because i found it's concurrency model interesting. Go gives you the ability to "get the best out of both worlds", all I/O is blocking, write synchronous code, but enjoy the full utilization of the CPU.

Go has an abstraction to Threads called 'Go Routines', which are basically user level threads, the 'Go Runtime' (which gets compiled in with your program) is in charge of scheduling the different Go Routines on real OS threads (let's say 1 per CPU) whenever a Go Routine performs a system call the 'Go Runtime' schedules another Go Routine to run in one of the OS threads, it 'multiplexes' the go-routines onto the OS threads.

User level threads isn't a new concept, Go's approach is nice, and simple, so I started wondering, why doesn't the JVM world use a similar abstraction, it's child's play compared to what usually happens there under the hood.

Then I found out it did, Sun's 1.2 JVM called them green threads which were user level threads, but the were only multiplexed into a single OS thread, they moved on to real OS threads to allow utilizing multi-core CPU's.

---

**Why wasn't this relevant in the JVM world after 1.2?** Am I failing to see the downsides of the Go approach? Maybe some concept that applies to Go, but would not be implementable on the JVM?

Comment: That's a very interesting and good-quality writeup. Sadly it doesn't fit into SO's Q&A paradigm. A note on 1.2 JVM's green threads: they were just an early implementation; I don't believe they were ever considered as a strategically good approach. It is certainly not desirable to have green threads as the only option.

Comment: Make any system call that blocks from your user-level thread - you will find out a downside.

Comment: In general, that's simply wrong, Martin. It only happens where the thread support is poor.

Comment: There was a discussion between Gosling and Joy (Sun) and several academics from UK universities at which the introduction of the event-driven (note: not "evented") CSP model might happen in Java. Joy was enthusiastic and blogged about it but finally Gosling vetoed the idea. At the time, the 'green threads' were giving poor performance and he chose to abandon them rather than adopt CSP. His lower-risk decision left us where we are today, sadly.

Comment: look at http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/

Comment: While his write-up is pretty extensive, I fail to see how the question "Why wasn't this relevant in the JVM world after 1.2 ?" is not constructive.

Comment: @Rick-777 you don't *need* green threads to implement CSP. You can quite happily do CSP with real OS threads too. All you have to do is layer something on top of the standard IPC (pipes, etc) to get CSP's strict blocking channels.

Comment: @Rick-777 "In general, that's simply wrong". Yes, it does depend on the thread support. For example, threads in Python are effectively user space threads, and the Global Interpreter Lock is a real problem.

Comment: @Matan - "But... it doesn't scale". I'm not so sure about that these days. If you look at a modern Intel or AMD chip there's a lot of inter-chip/core serial links these days (QPI for Intel, Hypertransport for AMD). They're used to implement an SMP environment, but those links get awful busy carrying cache update traffic, etc. In modern CPUs one might well be better off with blocking I/O between threads.